# Vue.js how to expose component data properties for use in third party script?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am wondering what the cleanest way to expose data properties on a single-file Vue component without polluting the global namespace is.

In my main entry file(app.js) for Vue I am setting up Vue like so:

```
import components from './components/components';

window.app = new Vue({
    el: '#vue',

    store,

    // etc.
});
```

My `components.js` imports all the components that I want to use as HTML snippets. Some of these components are import components on their own that are not directly set as components on my `root` instance.

What would be the best way to expose some data properties of certain single-file Vue components?

For instance I have a `Search.vue` component where I would like to send my first 3 objects from an array of results to Google Analytics:

```
// Expose this on `Search.vue`:

data: {
    // Filled with data from ajax request.
    results: []
}
```

My Vue instance is available globally. Is there an easy way to access a certain component perhaps by name or something?

**Edit**

So far the best option currently looks like accessing my property(which I have available inside my store) through a getter like so:

```
this.$store.getters.propertyINeed
```

Any suggestions on how to improve on this are welcome.

Comment: I see you use store, which I'm assuming you're using `Vuex`, can you put the data in the Vuex store instead?

Comment: And then just access it by using `app.$store` and calling my getters property on this object?

Comment: That's one way to do it, but I think if you can, you should do it inside the store (I'm writing a solution for it.)

Comment: @kevguy So I should expose the properties globally inside my store or something?

Comment: How do you send anything to Google analytics?

Comment: `Send` is no the right phrase here. Simply make a property global and let analytics pick up on it. That is what I am trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you store the data you need in a `Vuex` store. As you can see, the `srch-component` has a computed property which gives the result and there's a watcher that will automatically dispatch the data to the store. Then you can use something like `app.$store` to access the data without tampering the components.

Note that you can also better manage the store using modules ([link](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html)).

```js
Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    topSrchResult: []
  },
  mutations: {
    updateTopSrchResult: (state, payload) => {
      state.topSrchResult = payload
    }
  },
  actions: {
    UPDATE_TOP_SRCH_RESULT: ({ commit }, data) => {
        commit('updateTopSrchResult', data)
    }  
  }
})



Vue.component('srch-component', {
    template: `
      <div>
        <div>Input: <input v-model="inputVal" type="text"/></div>
        <div>Search Results:</div>
        <ul>
          <li v-for="item in srchResult">{{item}}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    `,
    data() {
        return {
          inputVal: '',
          dummyData: [
            'Scrubs', 'Hannah Montana', '30 Rock', 'Wizards of Waverly Place',
            'How I Met Your Mother', 'Community', 'South Park', 'Parks and Recreation',
            'The Office', 'Brooklyn Nine-Nine', 'Simpsons', 'Fringe', 'Chuck'
          ]            
        }
    },
    watch: {
        srchResult() {
          const payload = this.srchResult.length <= 3  ? this.srchResult : this.srchResult.slice(0,3)
          this.$store.dispatch('UPDATE_TOP_SRCH_RESULT', payload) 
        }
    },
    computed: {
      srchResult() {
        return this.dummyData
          .filter(
            (item) => item.toLowerCase().includes(this.inputVal.toLowerCase())
        )
      }
    }
})

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  computed: {
      topSrchResult() {
        return this.$store.state.topSrchResult 
      }
  },
  store
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/2.4.1/vuex.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>Top Results</div>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in topSrchResult">{{item}}</li>
  </ul>
  <srch-component></srch-component>
</div>
```